# Covering spaces of $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Put $\tilde X=\lbrace (exp(2\pi if(t)),t)| t\in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$ where 
$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any continuous function and let $\pi_1$ be
the projecction on the first coordinate. If we define $p:\tilde X\rightarrow 
S^1$ by $p=\pi_{1}|_{\tilde X}.$  Proof that if $f$ is strictly monotone
then $p$ is a covering map.

Comment: Just trying to clarify, is $\overline{X} \subseteq \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R}$?  I'm having trouble seeing precisely how this $\overline{X}$ is defined.

Comment: Yes, $\tilde X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}$, but this can be think like a susbset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and personally I think that is better.

Comment: @Sergio: Under the stated hypotheses, it's not even generally true that $f$ is a covering map _onto its image_. (For example, take $f(t) = e^{t}$.) Could you please check the hypotheses you're given?

Comment: Well, I will go to change the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; $p$ doesn't need to be surjective with the assumptions you state. $f$ could be a constant function, in which case $\pi_1\left. \right|_\tilde{X}$ is not a covering map.

**Edit:** Whoops, forgot the monotonicity. Daniel Rust points out in the comments that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}x$ is a monotone function where we don't get surjectivity.

Comment: But, over any disjonit set in the covering of the inverse image of $U_t \in   S^1$, I need proof that $p$ is surjective.

Comment: I don't think the constant function works as a counterexample.  The question asks "if $f$ is strictly monotone, ..." which a constant function would not be.

Comment: Sure, but something like $f=\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}(x)$ would work.